# php string replace by str_replace issue

Tags: php, string

i made a function to replace a words in a string by putting new words from an array.

this is my code

```
function myseo($t){
    $a = array('me','lord');
    $b = array('Mine','TheLord');    
    $theseotext = $t;
    $theseotext = str_replace($a,$b, $theseotext);
    return $theseotext;
}

echo myseo('This is me Mrlord');
```

the output is

> This is Mine MrTheLord

and it is wrong it should be print

> This is Mine Mrlord

because word (Mrlord) is not included in the array.

i hope i explained my issue in good way. any help guys

regards

Comment: you asked to replace `lord` and it did

Comment: yes but the word Mrlord is a word and i dont want to be change ... the code should change exactly the words in the array

Comment: you will be better of using regex

Answer (score 0):

According to the code it is correct, but you want it to isolate by word. You *could* simply do this:

```
function myseo($t){
    $a = array(' me ',' lord ');
    $b = array(' Mine ',' TheLord ');    
    return str_replace($a,$b, ' '.$t.' ');
}

echo myseo('This is me Mrlord');
```

keep in mind this is kind of a cheap hack since I surround the replace string with empty spaces to ensure both sides get considered. This wouldn't work for punctuated strings. The alternate would be to break apart the string and replace each word individually.

Comment: is there any way to do it without adding space before and after the words

Comment: definitely. You can use preg_replace and write a proper regex that targets intelligently. I'm sort of busy right now so I don't have much time to give an example, but I may later.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` doesn't look at full words only - it looks at any matching sequence of characters.

Thus, `lord` matches the latter part of `Mrlord`.

Answer (score 0):

use `str_ireplace` instead, it's case insensitive.